# Why doesn't the command run by timeout terminate when the time runs out?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell script which runs a Java program. When I run the shell script from the terminal, an exception error occurs and the command does not terminate even after the timeout.
This is what I run:

```
timeout -k 20s ./bbmap.sh
```

Comment: Does your shell script trap any signals?  Does the Java program trap any signals?  Have you tried adding `-s HUP` (or `-s 1`) or some other signal name or number? (Only use KILL as a last resort.)  Also, you aren't specifying the duration to let it sleep; you're specifying when the kill signal should be sent after the initial signal.  Try `timeout -k 20s 20s ./bbmap.sh`.  Are you redirecting errors somewhere?  (That said, the command isn't run at all if you don't specify a duration.  I was testing GNU `timeout` from `coreutils 8.24`, but running it on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.5.)

Comment: thanks, I tried using -s but that dint work. I am also trying to redirect the output to a text file also.

Comment: Which version of `timeout` are you using?  With the GNU `timeout` I was using, your command line fails — the invocation doesn't specify a timeout (it only specifies a time after which to use `kill -9` on the child after the main timeout has elapsed).  Consequently, you may be working with an older,  a newer, or just a different `timeout` rather than the GNU `timeout` I tested.  (I also have my own variant with different options — it predates the GNU `timeout` AFAIK — the oldest revision of mine was in 1989.)  Which variant of Linux are you using?